# Generic function which accepts only valid entity types for properties of single value or array type

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I have a set of entity-types which may refer to other entities (either as nullable single values or arrays).
For example:

```
type EntityBase = {
  type: string;
}

type EntityA = EntityBase & {
  type: "a",
}

type EntityB = EntityBase & {
  type: "b",
}

type EntityC = EntityBase & {
  type: "c",
}

type EntityTest = EntityBase & {
  type: "test",
  genericEntityList: Entity[],
  singleEntityAorNull: EntityA | null,
  entityBList: EntityB[],
  singleEntityCorNull: EntityC | null
}

type Entity = EntityA | EntityB | EntityC | EntityTest;
```

Now I want to create a generic function which

1. takes an instance of some entity
2. takes the name of some property to which to add (in case of list) or set (in case of single value) and entity
3. takes the entity to add/set to that field

So the signature should roughly look something like

```
function addEntity<ParentEntityClass extends Entity,
                   ParentEntityPropertyKey extends keyof ParentEntityClass,
                   EntityClass extends Entity>
                  (parentEntity: EntityBase,
                   propertyKey: ParentEntityPropertyKey,
                   entity: EntityClass) {
    ...
}
```

Now all of this should be type-safe such that it is impossible to pass invalid property-keys (one which is not entity-related) or pass incompatible entities depending on the property it is meant to be set to.
How can this be achieved ?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mZ11eN) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, please [edit] the question to include a test suite (like I've shown in the link) that demonstrates cases I haven't anticipated properly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This seems to work almost perfectly, except for null not being permitted for the fields singleEntityAorNull and singleEntityCorNull. Is there an easy fix for this ?

Comment: Note that you asked and I replied to this more than a week ago and I've essentially forgotten about what's going on here.  Maybe [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w842Pw) will work, but if I put more effort into addressing this, are you likely to respond sooner?  Otherwise it might not be worth it for me, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm very sorry it took so long to reply. I was very busy lately. I think the last modification does the job. I'll write up a answer soon. Thank you very much for your help. It is very appreciated.

Comment: Wait, you’ll write up an answer explaining my suggested approach? I think I’m probably in a better position to do that. Is there some reason you want to do it instead?

Comment: Ah cool. Yeah, that would be even better. I'm not a 100% sure I understand all the details just yet. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My inclination would be to make `addEntity()` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `T`, the type of `parentEntity` [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `Entity`, and in `K`, the type of `propertyKey` constrained to `keyof T`.  Then `entity` would have a type which is a function of the type `T[K]`, the property type you get by [indexing into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) a value of type `T` with a key of type `K`:

```
function addEntity<T extends Entity, K extends keyof T>(
  parentEntity: T,
  propertyKey: K,
  entity: EntityFromProp<T[K]>) {
}
```

So now we just have to define `EntityFromProp<T>`... here's one possibility:

```
type EntityFromProp<T> =
  T extends (infer E extends Entity)[] ? E : T;
```

This is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that checks if `T` is an array of some entity type and if so, evaluates to that entity type, and if not, just evaluates to `T`. This has the desired effect for the intended inputs:

```
type TestArr = EntityFromProp<EntityC[]>;
// type TestArr = EntityC
type TestNullableSingle = EntityFromProp<EntityB | null>;
// type TestNullableSingle = EntityB | null
```

I'm not overly concerned here with what happens if you pass in an unintended input:

```
type Whuh = EntityFromProp<EntityA[] | EntityC | Date>;
// type Whuh = EntityA | EntityC | Date
```

So just keep it in mind if you have use cases where that matters a lot.

---

Anyway, let's test it out with some values:

```
declare const test: EntityTest;
declare const entityA: EntityA;
declare const entityB: EntityB;
declare const entityC: EntityC;
```

The `"genericEntityList"` key requires an `Entity` entity:

```
// function addEntity<EntityTest, "genericEntityList">(
//   parentEntity: EntityTest, propertyKey: "genericEntityList", entity: Entity
// ): void
addEntity(test, "genericEntityList", entityA); // okay
addEntity(test, "genericEntityList", entityB); // okay 
addEntity(test, "genericEntityList", "oops"); // error
```

The `"singleEntityAorNull"` key requires an `EntityA | null` entity:

```
// function addEntity<EntityTest, "singleEntityAorNull">(
//   parentEntity: EntityTest, propertyKey: "singleEntityAorNull", entity: EntityA | null
// ): void
addEntity(test, "singleEntityAorNull", entityA); // okay
addEntity(test, "singleEntityAorNull", null); // okay
addEntity(test, "singleEntityAorNull", entityC); // error
```

The `"entityBList"` key requires an `EntityB` entity:

```
// function addEntity<EntityTest, "entityBList">(
//   parentEntity: EntityTest, propertyKey: "entityBList", entity: EntityB
// ): void
addEntity(test, "entityBList", entityB); // okay
addEntity(test, "entityBList", entityA); // error
```

The `"singleEntityCorNull"` key requires an `EntityC | null` entity:

```
// function addEntity<EntityTest, "singleEntityCorNull">(
//   parentEntity: EntityTest, propertyKey: "singleEntityCorNull", entity: EntityC | null
// ): void
addEntity(test, "singleEntityCorNull", entityC); // okay
addEntity(test, "singleEntityCorNull", entityA); // error
```

and then the `"type"` key, which I assume is unexpected, requires a `"test"` "entity":

```
// function addEntity<EntityTest, "type">(
//   parentEntity: EntityTest, propertyKey: "type", entity: "test"
// ): void
addEntity(test, "type", entityA); // error!
```

This last one is an error, which is good, although maybe it should be more restrictive and not even let you pass in `"type"`.  But again, that really depends on use cases and how likely this sort of problem is going to be, so I'm going to consider this out of scope for the question as asked, so the answer doesn't get even longer.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAECsFcGcBdQMYAsCGA7A5gS06WSBTaAvAe1B1gICcAzFBIs0AWxQGsSATLaABwA2KAJ6gCKaFhoAoSjXqNQAUTSwssYQCEJJAN7TQeYXwIAuUHGo4MAbmkBfabNXyGJFWo0BBMQA8qaFzQyqrqWjqg+oYaJuYARChxADQOTnJ0biGeWn4BQVlh2sSRBkaxoHEARsmpzlQZih5hAMK5BIHBTRpFeqUxZhUINY7S-QUaACpE8AC84+HFAGQl0cYDcVRwNYYY7TRYCF3CADK8sOZHANoAuimGkpgCBEdepNQAcpACAheh3qAAH1AaC+AjuYj+WlOcF+2U0N3BDwwTyOzTen2+sJagOBoNqYyOoDmLxxR00pMhrSBRymcDsozW8wAYtRSCwAAqsvgAHgmAD4iaUJm0OqAABQ4Wg0ZQi-JHACUN1AAH4ZeYJvTaJA0Ag1KQ0KAUFwuEdebLOpCkqAANLm0CcYSkWigfli0p8FDUdqwI7q8F8Lk0DTWgjCczW8HesJYjQstmc0g8iaXa3XPnykojMa02BeajUInM1kcrnc1E3Pl2EBlEg5vMF4mUhkmF3TDFCSpPADK1iehaOcZLibLkPJQJB30r0mr2bboJQnYIPceJEbcJxE4ETjGAHUkJAkP3IYOEzyXkrqZScQARFBUKczxl7g9H7I+S-ZKmgW9UJzSLgEAgQheog+pwHg0wxsIOZ2ABQGeiQCBgfAUbeFBXiwYBwGIchEJwlBmiYfBIFIWg4GocIzRQc09LVlqOp6gaRompCI7ZDmVpxLsaD7IckLQrAcR8m61aGB6XqqL68wcaAAaJkGwghmGFTcbxRwCckeHRvM05gPK5gAG6kFgXDSMxRxipssCcapVh8dkGlWhRXjyjYoDVqQ7AiGZxoWVZNl7HZ6lnJpFGaK57lgJ5IigD5LHZJZ0wBTxQX8SFnGkIm0BxBF1Y0Ky1BOHR2q6lg+qGr5rE0klFRIiikKvB8oJCSJYBiQhkmQlBMlySY1DBqG8R1c8DXos1TldfM764t8umgPpoBGSZcV+TVcTDS8Y3fKFDW5VFXnCCtkKJXAnEbaNTXbVam57aA0WHeZx3+bVvYjW+W0CDtn63flbxFWA9GleVj3ZGxYQyXEYUacJc3tRJPqTdVp2yYG-WKYNFRQ+lWkaARc0LUtpkg2EJ3WZjo6OTjWi3fdR0Jc9kMU9jzk-fmf1zYDjEVfFYRg5Ma3nZ+H0tbDskdQj2TdTVvUKUpQ2vaiwsTZL8xfpu+OGcZROVfTAsK5SStU80NMHXTJMM4LLSGyzbl5WzhX-aAnNlUxOu80jZMbGsIuiWL8NSR7Voy2jcsVP0X3aRs0xxBri1a2bGik5x4fK2ELm22Av3UAAhE4QA)